# Collecting GPS co-Ordinates

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin, gps

I am building a native android app using xamarin. The issue is, that the application collects and displays the coordinates perfectly on the emulator but when I put it on a smartphone (tried 2 samsung phones) it comes up with can't determine the current address. Extra information  data and locations are turned on so I am not sure where the issue is. Thanks for your help. here is the xammarin recipe encase that helps https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/

```
    [Activity(Label = "NewRoute")]
    public class NewRouteActivity : Activity, ILocationListener
    {

        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(NewRouteActivity).Name;
        TextView _addressText;
        Location _currentLocation;
        LocationManager _locationManager;

        string _locationProvider;
        TextView _locationText;


        public async void OnLocationChanged(Location location) {
            _currentLocation = location;
            if (_currentLocation == null)
            {
                _locationText.Text = "Unable to determine your location. Try again in a short while.";
            }
            else
            {
                _locationText.Text = string.Format("{0:f6},{1:f6}", _currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
                Address address = await ReverseGeocodeCurrentLocation();
                DisplayAddress(address);
            }
        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider) { }

        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider) { }

        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras) { }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CreatetRoute);

            _addressText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.address_text);
            _locationText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.location_text);
            FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.get_address_button).Click += AddressButton_OnClick;

            InitializeLocationManager();


            Button btnEndPoint = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnEndPoint);
            btnEndPoint.Click += new EventHandler(AfterPointsCollected);
        }
        //Location Stuff
        void InitializeLocationManager()
        {
            _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
            Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria
            {
                Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine
            };
            IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = _locationManager.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);

            if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
            {
                _locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
            }
            else
            {
                _locationProvider = string.Empty;
            }
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Using " + _locationProvider + ".");
        }
        //Override OnResume so that Activity1 will begin listening to the LocationManager when the activity comes into the foreground:
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
        }
        async void AddressButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (_currentLocation == null)
            {
                _addressText.Text = "Can't determine the current address. Try again in a few minutes.";
                return;
            }

            Address address = await ReverseGeocodeCurrentLocation();
            DisplayAddress(address);
        }

        async Task<Address> ReverseGeocodeCurrentLocation()
        {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            IList<Address> addressList =
                await geocoder.GetFromLocationAsync(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude, 10);

            Address address = addressList.FirstOrDefault();
            return address;
        }

        void DisplayAddress(Address address)
        {
            if (address != null)
            {
                StringBuilder deviceAddress = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < address.MaxAddressLineIndex; i++)
                {
                    deviceAddress.AppendLine(address.GetAddressLine(i));
                }
                // Remove the last comma from the end of the address.
                _addressText.Text = deviceAddress.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                _addressText.Text = "Unable to determine the address. Try again in a few minutes.";
            }
        }

        //Override OnPause and unsubscribe Activity1 from the LocationManager when the activity goes into the background:
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
        }
        //Changing Activity
        void AfterPointsCollected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //context   //activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(AfterPointsCollectedActivity));
            //starts the activity with the intent above
            this.StartActivity(intent);

        }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what your error message is. Provide your LogCat or screenshots. Have you tried to debug this to determine where in your code the issue is occurring.

Comment: The issue is that there is no error it works perfectly on a emulator but it just doesn't work when its compiled on a mobile device it just says every thing is null as if its not getting the gps co-ordinates even though location and data are both on  which is why my error messages pop up.

Comment: On the devices have you tried using another app to get the location, such as Google Maps. Ensure that your devices are correctly getting the location for those apps.

Comment: Yep google maps work on both of the devices. I tried after my app failed just to check.

Comment: is there more than one Fine LocationProvider avaialable?  Have you tried to use one other than First()?  Do you have Fine location permissions enabled in your Manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Your phones are probably running MarshMallow which now require that you request permission for location services.

You can read more about it here https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/. You might want to use this Nuget package that handles all that for you. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Geolocator